# NDSolveValue is unable to provide a solution because of boundary conditions

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method, physics

I have the following Mathematica code for solving a partial differential equation, which I took from [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1802.02084) (page 6, 10) for `B = 0` (which has `zh = 1.63`) case:

```
f[z_, zh_] := 1 - z^4/zh^4
ϕ[z_] := 1.2^2 z^2 + 2.2 z + Tanh[1/(2.2 z) - 1.2/0.55]
Σl[z_] := E^-ϕ[z]/z

NDSolveValue[
 {
   D[σl[ω, z], z] == (I ω)/(f[z, 1.63] Σl[z]) (σl[ω, z]^2 - Σl[z]^2), 
   σl[ω, 1.63] == Σl[1.63], σl[0, z] == 0
 },
 σl, {ω, 0, 20}, {z, 0.001, 1.63}
]
```

I am using the same boundary condition as they suggest in `equation(42)` but seems like it is creating an issue for Mathematica. Any help in this regard would be truly beneficial!

**Edit**

Since, in the paper they provide just one boundary condition, So I edit my original code, and now `NDSolveValue` provides a solution but when I plot it, I get an empty plot.

```
NDSolveValue[{D[\[Sigma]l[\[Omega], z], 
    z] == (I \[Omega])/(f[z, 1.63] \[CapitalSigma]l[
        z]) (\[Sigma]l[\[Omega], z]^2 - \[CapitalSigma]l[z]^2), 
  DirichletCondition[\[Sigma]l[\[Omega], z] == \[CapitalSigma]l[z], 
   True]}, \[Sigma]l, {\[Omega], 0, 20}, {z, 0.001, 1.63}]
```

Comment: "it is creating an issue" - what do you mean exactly? What problem are you encountering? What have you tried to solve them? How did you narrow down the problem to the boundary conditions?

Comment: The boundary conditions `σl[ω, 1.63] == Σl[1.63], σl[0, z] == 0` are inconsistent because `Σl[1.63]!=0`!

Comment: Actually in the paper, they provide just one condition, it was my fault to add another one, please see the edited question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> NDSolveValue provides a solution but when I plot it, I get an empty
> plot.

This is because solution is complex. You can plot its real value, it imaginary value or its absolute value. Mathematica will give empty plot if asked to plot complex value. Need to use special Plot commands or ask it to plot the real/abs or imaginary values.

```
f[z_, zh_] := 1 - z^4/zh^4
ϕ[z_] := 1.2^2  z^2 + 2.2  z + Tanh[1/(2.2  z) - 1.2/0.55]
Σl[z_] := E^-ϕ[z]/z
sol = NDSolveValue[{D[σl[ω, z], 
     z] == (I  ω)/(f[z, 1.63]  Σl[
         z])  (σl[ω, z]^2 - Σl[z]^2), 
   DirichletCondition[σl[ω, z] == Σl[z], True]}, σl, {ω, 0, 20}, {z, 0.001, 1.63}]
```

You can see it is complex solution by trying some random values

sol[1, 1]

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And now

```
Plot3D[Re[sol[ω, z]], {ω, 0, 20}, {z, 0.001, 1.63}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Or

```
Plot3D[Abs[sol[ω, z]], {ω, 0, 20}, {z, 0.001, 1.63}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]